# Custom file names in Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-config

How to specify a spring boot application to access only a specific `.properties` file among other files in my Spring Cloud Config Server.

My Spring Cloud Config has the following files:
`application.properties`,`order-dev.properties`,`inventory-dev.properties`,
all my db and messaging properties are in order-dev and inventory-dev files.

Now I wish to move those properties to `orderdb-dev`, `inventorydb-dev`, `ordermsg-dev` and `inventorymsg-dev` files.

How do I configure my `order` and `inventory` service to pick the property from `orderdb-dev`, `inventorydb-dev`, `ordermsg-dev` and `inventorymsg-dev` files ?  I have been going around to find the property for the same. Read through the official documentation and felt lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add a bootstrap.yml file under resources folder. Then add the below properties.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: order   
  cloud:
    config:
      name: ${spring.application.name}, orderdb, ordermsg
      profile: dev
```

This way, it will first load the properties from order-dev.properties file. Then orderdb-dev.properties and then ordermsg-dev.properties.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Where is the documentation mentioned for this ? I read the whole official doc and couldn't find this property.

Comment: Even i couldn't find the doc reference. There is a GitHub issue which mentions this solution and an ask for doc update. Not sure if it was done ever.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/618

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your config with custom file name is `myboot.properties`.
According to [documentation to externalizable configs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) there are many ways to start the application, with command line parameter `--spring.config.name`:

```java
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myboot
```

In command line we specify `myboot` but the Spring Boot will search for `myboot.properties`. Many property files can be added comma separated like this:

```java
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myboot,myboot2,myboot3
```

Now common properties from `myboot.properties` will be overridden by `myboot2.properties` then overridden by `myboot3.properties`.

Another option, full config names in `--spring.config.location`:

```java
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/myboot.properties
```

Now filename must contain the file extension. Arbitrary extensions **can not** be used, because extensions unknown to Spring Boot will generate errors. `--spring.config.location` also supports multiple comma separated config names.

Alternatively exactly the same can be achieved in the source code, without changing command line:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyBoot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(
            new Class<?>[] {MyBoot.class, MyController.class},
            new String[]{"--spring.config.name=myboot"});
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyBoot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(
            new Class<?>[] {MyBoot.class, MyController.class},
            new String[]{"--spring.config.location=classpath:/myboot.properties"});
```

Or you might want to avoid getting rid of existing command line arguments:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyBoot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] newArgs = Stream.concat (
                Stream.of (args),
                Stream.of ("--spring.config.location=classpath:/myboot.properties"))
            .toArray(String[]::new);

        SpringApplication.run(
            new Class<?>[] {MyBoot.class, MyController.class},
            newArgs);
```

So, the above code is just an idea, which might not flexible enough, make as flexible as required.